# Excel VBA - Return SQL Data To Excel Table

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am having a little trouble returning SQL data into an Excel table, instead of dropping the data into the cell I specify (when not using a table) it pushes the whole table to the right.

Does anyone know how I can get it to populate the table as I want to make use of splicers etc. to filter the data. I know I could import the data then turn it into a table but if there's a quicker, simpler way then I'd rather that.

Right now the code I'm using is:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="ODBC;DSN=<dbname>", Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A13"))
                    .CommandText = strSQL
                    .Name = "Query"
                    .FieldNames = False
                    .RowNumbers = False
                    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                    .PreserveFormatting = True
                    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                    .BackgroundQuery = True
                    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                    .SavePassword = False
                    .SaveData = True
                    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
                    .RefreshPeriod = 0
                    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                End With

                ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
```

Many thanks in advance.

Dan

Comment: What are you doing now?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the main post accordingly.